# Throttle operation resulting in a slow performance on window phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am building a WP7 application which heavily uses RX and I came across a problem. When adding Throttle with a value bigger that 20 ms it significantly reduces performance.

**The snippet below pinpoints the issue:**

```
var moveObs = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                    h => this.MouseMove += h,
                    h => this.MouseMove -= h);

// Observe dragging
var yObs = (from x in moveObs
            select -(x.EventArgs.GetPosition(this).Y - _initY));

var result = yObs.SkipWhile(y => !_isDragging)
                 .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33));

result.TimeInterval()
      .Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine("Mouse move interval: " + x));
```

**Here is output of the snippet:**

```
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.dll'
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1e18) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Mouse move interval: 80@00:00:04.1920000
Mouse move interval: -160@00:00:00.2900000
Mouse move interval: -126@00:00:00.6710000
The thread '<No Name>' (0x22a4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Mouse move interval: -90@00:00:01.0460000
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2514) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Mouse move interval: -113@00:00:00.3250000
The thread '<No Name>' (0x270c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Mouse move interval: 108@00:00:12.1420000
The thread '<No Name>' (0x186c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Mouse move interval: 221@00:00:01.4860000
```

So to my understanding Throttle will create a thread from thread pool and won't block UI and it should be quite efficient, shouldn't it?

**Question**
So why is performance so slow. I am a novice in RX so I am probably missing something here.

**Edit**

**Here is another sample which reproduces the same issue:**

```
var oneNumberPerSecond = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

var lowNums = from n in oneNumberPerSecond
              select n;


lowNums.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
       .TimeInterval()
       .Subscribe(lowNum => Debug.WriteLine(lowNum));
```

In my understanding this should print a number every 100 ms, however it doesn't print any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that it's slow - what you've described is exactly the behavior of Throttle.

Throttle produces a value when the stream stops producing a value for the specified duration.

Let me break down your repro:

```
var oneNumberPerSecond = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
```

This is a cold observable which produces a value every 10 msecs.

```
var lowNums = from n in oneNumberPerSecond
              select n;
```

This does nothing really. It's equivalent to `oneNumberPerSecond.Select(i => i)`

```
lowNums.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
```

This produces a stream which will produce a value whenever `lowNums` stops producing a value for 100msecs. But since `lowNums` produces a value every 10 msecs, there won't be a time when nothing happens for 100msecs.

Comment: I might add that `Throttle` isn't exactly the best name for this method.

Comment: You are absolute right, I mixed it up with Sample. But in fact the issue with performance still exist, I think this is very similar issue to what I am having: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/e6824c74-9c23-421f-bc25-81305b0e2a22/

Comment: @Asti - BTW, `Interval` produces **cold** observables, *not* hot.

Comment: @Vitalij Btw, if you're looking for something which ignores burst, `Sample` isn't the right solution.

Comment: @Vitalij Not sure what exactly you want - in your example, do you want to be notified when the user stops dragging for a while, or do you want to be notified when the user starts dragging, but skip values which are coming in too fast (burst scenario)?

Comment: @Asti It is a burst scenario I would think.

Comment: StackOverflow is warning me about long comments. Could you ask this as another question? I feel that this is a common problem which would benefit from more creative solutions.